# Nestjs on EC2: JavaScript heap out of memory issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, nestjs

I am running nest project on t2 micro. Initially it was working fine but now after adding some other modules, it hangs while making build and says "Javascript heap out of memory".

Please help me with the possible reasons on why this might happen.

Answer (score 2):

**--max-old-space-size** can increase heap memory

connect ssh to ec2 and open the .bashrc file using nano like so:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

The remaining steps are similar with the Mac steps from above, except we would most likely be using ~/.bashrc by default (as opposed to ~/.zshrc). So these values would need to be substituted!

[Link to Nodejs Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--max-old-space-sizesize-in-megabytes)